# How to compute (i+1 - i) in a list of vectors

Tags: r, for-loop, lapply

I have a list with 29 vectors (each vector with different lengths) like this:

```
my_list
[1] 1 12 23 34 38 
[2] 2 12 21 38 47 56 71  
 .
 .
[29] 14 22 81 88 91 94
```

**I need to compute ( *i+1  - i* ) for each vector of the list (my_list).**
Example:

```
my_list
[1] (12-1) (23-12)  (34-23) (38-34)
[2] (12-2) (21-12)  (38-21) (47-38) (56-47) (71-56)
 .
 .
[29] (22-14) (81-22)  (88-81) (91-88) (94-91)
```

I tried a for loop:

```
res <- list()
for(i in 1:29) {
    for(j in 1:length(my_list[[i]])){
        my_res <- list(my_list[[i]][j+1] - my_list[[i]][j])
        res[i] <- my_res
```

But the result gives only the first value for each vector of the list:

```
res
[1] 11
[2] 10
 .
 .
[29] 8
```

There is a way to do it with apply-like functions?

Comment: `lapply(my_list, diff)`?

Comment: Your code does not seem to be complete.

Comment: @Parfait, I don't interpret the OP to at all suggest a constraint of identical vector lengths. I suggest bringing `data.frame` into this discussion can be very confusing to R novices.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't really know about your double-`for` loop, but there are a couple of much-more-efficient ways to approach this type of problem.

[*Vectorization*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Array_programming) is something that R does very well. So much better, in fact, that the brute-force methods that are natural in some languages can still work in R but are significantly slower.

> Side note: R's `for` loops used to be less efficient than they are now, so many people still *strongly* discourage their use in favor of functions from the `apply` family. Two points: that fact is no longer true; and that is a different type of looping construct than I'm talking about here. So when I discourage `for` loops in this case, it is in favor of *vectorizing* the math, not `apply`ing it.

Here's some data:

```
my_list <- list(
  c(1, 12, 23, 34, 38),
  c(2, 12, 21, 38, 47, 56, 71),
  c(14, 22, 81, 88, 91, 94)
)
```

I'll demonstrate on a single vector of this list:

```
v <- my_list[[1]]
v
```

I interpret what you said as `v[i+1] - v[i]` for each `i` in sequence of indices (except 1, since `v[0]` is not defined in R). To do this as a vector, this is *"start with all numbers except the first, then subtract all numbers except the last"*.

```
v[-1]
# [1] 12 23 34 38
v[-length(v)]
# [1]  1 12 23 34
v[-1] - v[-length(v)]
# [1] 11 11 11  4
```

This is effectively

```
c(12, 23, 34, 38) - c(1, 12, 23, 34)
c(12-1, 23-12, 34-23, 38-34)
```

Now that we know how to do this efficiently *once*, let's streamline that operation and map it to each vector within the list. R does have a function that does this for us:

```
diff(v)
# [1] 11 11 11  4
```

but in case your future needs include more specific (non-general) operations, we could write our own function for this specific operation:

```
my_func <- function(vec) vec[-1] - vec[-length(vec)]
```

Now here is a classic use of one of the mapping functions: `lapply` applies a single function to each element of a `list`, and returns a same-length `list` with the return values.

> Side note: when I need to decide between `for` and `lapply` (for instance), I ask myself if I care about the calculation on each element (such as this case, where I want the `diff` of the vector), or if I'm just interested in the [side-effect](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Side_effect_(computer_science)) (e.g., plotting something, saving files). If the former, then `lapply` or its kin is appropriate; if the latter, often `for` loops. This is not a 100% heuristic, but it's generally pretty good.

```
lapply(my_list, my_func)
# [[1]]
# [1] 11 11 11  4
# [[2]]
# [1] 10  9 17  9  9 15
# [[3]]
# [1]  8 59  7  3  3
```

(Similarly, `lapply(my_list, diff)` works.) There are similar `*apply*` functions with slightly different benefits, requirements, and limitations. (There are also several tutorials that already go into it, and SO is not intended to be a tutorial-site.)

---

I really do discourage the use of `for` loops here, partly for `lapply`, partly for vectorization, but to help you understand why your implementation did not work:

- if you need to iterate over each element of a list:

  - it is preferred to *not* hard-code `1:29`, instead use something that depends on the vector itself, such as `length(my_list)`, so `1:length(my_list)` might seem appropriate (as you correctly use in your second loop), but ...
  - it has happened that this list at some point is of length 0, but `for (i in 1:0)` does *not* do what one would hope. To be clear, I would hope that it would do nothing, but `1:0` resolves into a vector, length 2, values 1 and 0 (and this is just wrong in most cases that use this flow control). I recommend replacing `for (i in 1:length(my_list))` with `for (i in seq_along(my_list))` or `for (i in seq_len(length(my_list)))` (`seq_along` provides indices along a vector/list, it will give no numbers if its list is length 0; and `seq_len` smartly gives a 0-length vector if its argument is 0. Both can be found in [`?seq`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-patched/library/base/html/seq.html).)
- when `i` is 1 and `j` is 2, you store `list(12-1)` in `res[1]`; when j is 3, you *overwrite* `res[1]` with `list(23-12)`, so you've lost your previous calculations in vector 1. This is why each element in your list is length 1.
- your inner loop (`j`) is going all the way to the end of a vector (`length(my_list[[i]])`); at this point, `my_list[[i]][j+1]` is pointing beyond the end of the vector, so it is resolving to `NA` (try `my_list[[1]][999999]`), which is why all values in `res` are `NA`. To fix this, either use `1:(length(my_list[[i]])-1)` or preferably `seq_length(my_list[[i]])[-1]` to drop the first (so we'll do `(j) - (j-1)` instead of `(j+1) - (j)`).

  - If you *must* preserve the `(j+1) - (j)` indexing logic, then use something like `seq_along(my_list[[i]])[-length(my_list[[i]])]` or `head(seq_along(my_list[[i]]),n=-1)`, where `n=-1` means all but the last one.

This is a corrected version of your code:

```
resouter <- list()
for (i in seq_along(my_list)) {
  resinner <- numeric(0)
  for (j in seq_along(my_list[[i]])[-1]) {
    resinner[j] <- my_list[[i]][j] - my_list[[i]][j-1]
  }
  resouter[[i]] <- resinner[-1] # since j starts at 2, first one is always NA
}
resouter
# [[1]]
# [1] 11 11 11  4
# [[2]]
# [1] 10  9 17  9  9 15
# [[3]]
# [1]  8 59  7  3  3
```

But I think that `lapply(my_list, my_func)` or even `lapply(my_list, diff)` are much more succinct (and faster).

Comment: It works very well. Thank you so much for the detailed response.